# Create new directory in parent directory of current directory -- ROR FileUtils.mkdir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fileutils

This is my basic hierarchy ... `MYPROJECTS/MYRAILSAPP/source_code_folders`

- I have a folder MYPROJECTS that holds my ror applications
- My application source code is held in a folder called MYRAILSAPP which is within MYPROJECTS
- Source code is in subdirectories within MYRAILSAPP

I use **FileUtils.mkdir** in `MYRAILSAPP/app/controllers/files_controller.rb`

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
    layout 'files'
  def home
  end
  def index
    if File.exist?('new')

    else
      files = Dir.glob('*')
      FileUtils.mkdir 'new'
      FileUtils.cp_r files, 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

This creates a new directory in MYRAILSAPP so it is `MYRAILSAPP/new`

I am wanting to create the new directory so it is `MYPROJECTS/new`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define that directory as a Pathname:

```
path = Rails.root.join('..', 'new')
```

To create it on disk:

```
path.mkpath
```

To check if it already exists:

```
path.exist?
```

See the [`Pathname`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) documentation for more things you can do.